# Fetching value from other database table based on similar field in other table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

1. new_categories
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]
2. new_products
   [![enter image description here][2]][2]

While displaying in new_products in front end - i.e prod_cat_id - i can display in

```
<?php echo $item->prod_cat_id; ?>
```

But its resulting in numeric information like 1,2,3,4 etc

However, The prod_cat_id field in table new_products is exactly similar to id field in table new_categories

How is it possible through mysql that column prod_cat_id in table newcar_products be matched to id field in table newcar_categories and when matched the display value will be echo will be of cat_name

```
<?php echo $item->cat_name; ?>
```

**Edited Revised code**

Code Tried
Executed this Query in Mysql

```
 SELECT #__new_categories.*, #__new_products.* from #__new_categories inner join #__new_products on #__new_products.prod_cat_id = #__new_categories.id
```

It was able to perfectly join in both table with Output as below
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

However, it seems a condition is missing in which when this code executed, 
cat_name displaying all categores

It should match show only one single cat_name matching against prod_cat_id

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
                    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "SELECT #__new_categories.*, #__new_products.* from #__new_categories inner join #__new_products on #__new_products.prod_cat_id = #__new_categories.id";                       

$db->setQuery($query);                                  
$results = $db->loadObjectList();  
foreach($results as $row){
   echo $row->cat_name;
}
 ?>
```

Tried this but All values in database under cat_name are displayed in instead of one cat_name against matching prod_cat_id

see the Output[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: You're looking for the `JOIN` keyword: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: @David - I have updated the code with join statement, but its showing php  notice of Array to string conversion and output as array. can you pl see to it

Comment: *What specifically* is showing this error message?  Is the error coming from SQL code?  From PHP code?  Which line?  What are the runtime values when it happens?  Nobody here can debug your code on your machine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using select  and inner join

```
 select 
     new_categories.cat_name as cat_name
   , new_categories.cat_parent as cat_parent
   , new_products.prod_name  as prod_name
 from new_categories 
 inner join new_products on new_products.prod_cat_id = new_categories.id
```

The query should  return all the object form database that meet the join condition so for echo the result you should use a foreach

```
$results = $db->loadObjectList();  
foreach($results as $row){
   echo $row->cat_name . ' - ' .  $row->prod_name . '<br />' ;
}
```

If you need a single category  you can eg (cat id = 2)

```
 select 
     new_categories.cat_name as cat_name
   , new_categories.cat_parent as cat_parent
   , new_products.prod_name  as prod_name
 from new_categories 
 inner join new_products on new_products.prod_cat_id = new_categories.id
 where new_categories.id = 2
```

or if you need only a product you can eg:product id 3

```
 select 
     new_categories.cat_name as cat_name
   , new_categories.cat_parent as cat_parent
   , new_products.prod_name  as prod_name
 from new_categories 
 inner join new_products on new_products.prod_cat_id = new_categories.id
 where new_products.id = 3
```

Comment: Have you error .. ? please show me the error message

Comment: I have update the answer using alias for column name .. hope is useful

Comment: Try var_dump($row) and check for the property name of the column name

Comment: You should execute the query in your mysql  console/ide  and check if you obtain the expected result . if not  .. build a proper query and use it in $query .. let me know

Comment: I have edited the question, the sql query is perfectly working basis the 1st reply, but only issue is that its displaying all values under cat_name - while i want an output which should display cat_name for matching prod_cat_id. Can you pl advise in

Comment: I have update the answer with select for a category  or a product i hope is this what you are  looking for  ..i have also edit the echo for show cat and prod name

Comment: Yes it works - just last instead of numeric 3 in  where new_products.id = 3. How to echo in echo $item->prod_cat_id; instead of numeric value

Comment: @Ruchika   ..1 )  you want the last product   id  instead of a fidex value?  2 ) which field you need in echo ?  product.cat_id or product.cat_name or something other ?.. please be clear ..